# How to mock, in jest, a module's constructor method's return object while changing implementation per test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

How can i mock and change the implementation of a constructor per test?

I am looking into the `lru-cache` lib and you call it something like this

```
const cache = new LRU({
  max: 500,
  ttl: 1000 * 60 * 15,
  updateAgeOnGet: false,
  updateAgeOnHas: false,
});
```

now the `cache` variable will have a `get` and `set` function, i am trying to change just the `get` implementation per test. So far mocking the entire module and attempting to call `mockImplementation` on either the constructor and/or get function, doesnt reflect the changes when the test calls the function i am testing (it just has the default mocking)

Here is one of the things I have tried

```
const LRU = require('lru-cache');
jest.mock('lru-cache');
```

and in my test file

```
it('should blah blah', () => {
    LRU.mockImplementation(() => ({
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(data => ({
        response: data,
      })),
      set: jest.fn()
    }));

    // call function in a file that uses lru-cache
  });
```

I also tried not mocking the constructor buy mocking the `get` function directly,

however, in all my attempts, when I log the object returned from the constructor in the code, it is a defualt mocking of the module but the `get` implementation is not there.

Now if i call and log something like this within the test file (not the method that uses it)

```
cache.get.mockImplementation(identifier => ({
   response: identifier,
}));
```

It does show the changes. So it appears the `mockImplementation` does not stick

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock it like this, outside the test. You can remove the `requireActual` if you do not need it.

```js
jest.mock('lru-cache', () => {
  const lruCacheOriginal = jest.requireActual('lru-cache');
  return function () {
    return {
      ...lruCacheOriginal,
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(data => ({
        response: data,
      })),
    }
  }
});

it('should blah blah', () => {
  // call function in a file that uses lru-cache
});
```

You can check also if your `Jest` config does not have mock resetting option enabled by default. Or just add following in your `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "resetMocks": false
}
```